# How to echo something without rendering something in YII2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to echo something in an actionpage.

lets say i want to echo `hello word` within yii layout.

what i know is to write hello word to a file (hello.php in views) and use `$this->render('hello');`

so how to make it shorter, like `$this->echo('hello word');`, so YII will display `hello word` inside layout?

Comment: I updated the answer. I think `$this->renderContent('hello word')` is the one you are looking for to output the message inside the main layout but without rendering the action file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rendering a HTML view is not a requirement. those 2 actions should output  the message:

```
public function actionHello()
{
    echo 'hello word !';
}

public function actionHello2()
{
    return 'hello word !';
}
```

in fact the built-in `yii\rest\Controller` and its child `ActiveController` used for REST api are returning data the same way it is done in the second example `actionHello2()`. except that they are using the [ContentNegotiator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator.html) filter to output JSON and/or XML instead of plain text:

```
'contentNegotiator' => [
    'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
    'formats' => [
        'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        'application/xml' => Response::FORMAT_XML,
    ],
],
```

---

In case you need to render the action view without the main layout you can use [renderPartial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#renderPartial()-detail):

```
public function actionAbout()
{
    echo 'hello word !';
    return $this->renderPartial('about');
}
```

If what you need is to render the main layout and outputting data without rendering the action view you can use [renderContent](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#renderContent()-detail):

```
public function actionHello()
{
    return $this->renderContent('hello word !');
}
```

more rendering options may also be found in related [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#renderPartial()-detail).